# BufferedWriter writing char with MSB 1

Tags: java, hex, bufferedreader

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
char[] test = new char[1];
test[0]=(char)128;
writer.write(test,0,1);
writer.flush();
```

Invoking using this command;
java File > out

and then examining "out" with a hex editor, I am expecting to get the byte 0x80 at the start of the file and nothing following it. Instead I get 0x3F.
By doing the same code with something different, ie, 64, I get the expected hex of 0x40.

Comment: `BufferedWriter` is a character oriented stream, use `BufferedOutputStream` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BufferedWriter` is a character oriented stream, so the bytes you write gets encoded to something different which you see in the file. Use a `BufferedOutputStream` which is designed to handle such types of binary data.

Comment: Ah yes, that fixed it, thank you.
Same principle with BufferedReader?

Comment: @ChristianWright Same, `BufferedInputStream` for binary and the other for character.

Answer (score 0):

In this case OutputStreamWriter converts characters into bytes using the platform's default character encoding. If you want to see 0x80 (128) in the file use `new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "ISO-8859-1");`

Answer (score 0):

As per Java 6 API for BufferedWriter, it says, "Without buffering, each invocation of a print() method would cause characters to be converted into bytes that would then be written immediately to the file, which can be very inefficient."

For more information on the same your can visit [the link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)